# io.undertow.request remote peer closed connection before all data could be read

Tags: java, wildfly, icefaces

I'm running ejb project on wildfly 10 and encountered this error message,

```
UT000128: Remote peer closed connection before all data could be read
```

Is the above message something to be concern of?

There isn't much information on the web. These are some references:

- io.undertow (http://undertow.io/)
- NIO (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_(Java))
- API (https://access.redhat.com/webassets/avalon/d/red-hat-jboss-enterprise-application-platform/7.0.0/javadocs/io/undertow/UndertowMessages.html).

Below is the stack trace,

```
15:45:11,650 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-29) UT005023: Exception handling request to /OV3WEB/block/receive-updated-views: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: UT000128: Remote peer closed connection before all data could be read
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.parseFormData(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:764)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.getParameter(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:636)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.ServletRequestResponse.containsParameter(ServletRequestResponse.java:118)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.RequestVerifier.service(RequestVerifier.java:29)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.ThreadBlockingAdaptingServlet.service(ThreadBlockingAdaptingServlet.java:25)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.EnvironmentAdaptingServlet.service(EnvironmentAdaptingServlet.java:63)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.service(SessionDispatcher.java:53)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionVerifier.service(SessionVerifier.java:26)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:131)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.BlockingServlet.service(BlockingServlet.java:56)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: UT000128: Remote peer closed connection before all data could be read
    at io.undertow.conduits.FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.exitRead(FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.java:338)
    at io.undertow.conduits.FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.read(FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.java:255)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSourceChannel.read(ConduitStreamSourceChannel.java:127)
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSourceChannel.read(DetachableStreamSourceChannel.java:209)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$ReadDispatchChannel.read(HttpServerExchange.java:2231)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.FormEncodedDataDefinition$FormEncodedDataParser.doParse(FormEncodedDataDefinition.java:133)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.FormEncodedDataDefinition$FormEncodedDataParser.parseBlocking(FormEncodedDataDefinition.java:251)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.parseFormData(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:762)
    ... 39 more
```

**Edit: 14 November 2016**

With regards to */{app}/block/send-receive-updates* or */{app}/block/receive-updated-views*, these are part of the heartbeat monitoring mechanism in ICEfaces component to maintain connectivity between the web server and the client browser.

From my understanding from sources:

- http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/5605.page;jsessionid=2785F9DB2C6A32F92AD3A05BF2F3F726#24788
- http://res.icesoft.org/docs/latest/htmlguide/devguide/AdvancedTopics6.html

Comment: It's hard to see what this message means. It is HTTP, which means TCP, which means that the close *can't* be received before all pending data is read. Possibly it means that a data length was supplied and the amount of data read before the close was less than indicated by the length.

Answer (score 1):

This error may occur when your server lost the socket connection with the client mainly due to a timeout or by forcefully closing the connection in either end.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error code (UT000128) while my application wanted to read the request body after some retry mechanism was executed. It will consume the payload so that I couldn't read them again and the Untertow returned UT000128.

My solution is to use wrapper to duplicate the request body in retry mechanism. If you are running into the same scenario, I hope this helpful.

Comment: Thanks @LHCHIN, will try and see.

Comment: is retry in client side or in server side?

Comment: @Hai Wang Hi, you can reference to this issue [Fix zuul post retry](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/pull/2209), they have fixed this bug already!